# Replace " " with %20 inside a fetchcall

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express, urlencode

I know that the question on **how to replace " " (space) with %20** is already asked on SO but I need to know where I can implement it - I am using *React Native* as my frontend and *NodeJS(ExpressJS)* as my backend connected to a *PostgreSQL DB*.

Is it possible to use `bodyparser urlencoded` to achieve this? I just need it inside 1 or 2 querys not for all.

My frontend part: (calling this on componentDidMount)

```
  getData("username")
  .then(data => data)
  .then(value => {
    this.setState({username: value})
  fetch(`http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:6969/api/hours/unlock/'${value}'`)    // replace " " mit %20 ?!?!?! 
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(result => {
    console.log("** UuNamMe **" + this.state.username)
    console.log("Res from  UnlockTabelle : " + result)
    console.log("Res from  UnlockTabelle[0] : " + result[0])
  })
  .catch(err => console.log("ErrorLog: @unlock : " + err))
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

my backend part:

```
  static unlockUser(username, callback) {
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM unlock WHERE name = '${username}'`, (err, res) => {
      if (err.error) {
        callback(err);
      }
      callback(res);
    });
  }

  static lockUser(username, callback) {
    db.query(`DELETE FROM unlock WHERE name = '${username}'`, (err, res) => {
      if (err.error) {
        callback(err);
      }
      callback(res);
    });
  }
```

---

```
router.get("/unlock/:username", (req,res) => {
  const username = req.params.username
  Hours.unlockUser(username, (err, result) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.json(err)
    }
    return res.json(result)
  })
})

router.delete("/lock/:username" , (req, res) => {
  const username = req.params.username
  Hours.lockUser(username, (err, result) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.json(err)
    }
    return res.json(result)
  })
})
```

If I would like to encode the URL to **replace " " with %20** where would that happen? On my backend with bodyparser or in my frontend if so how would that look like?

Comment: Something went wrong when unlocking my username, could you check this please. Here my data: `var username = "'; SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE '1' = '1"`

Comment: I dont rlly get what u mean but it works anyways now.

Comment: Don't trust little Bobby Tables! https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: :D :D right I get what you are saying - if I consider to secure my app do I need to sanitize inside the postgreDB or inside my App(frontend or backend) - ty

Comment: No not frontend, this is just something your backend can do. Your best option will be to use prepared statements.

Comment: Ok what kind of statements do you mean? Also do I do this in my Node/Express Server or in the DB also? __-- just found sanitize npm package might look into it if it is good

Comment: Mostly your db has some kind of function like `executeSQL(sql: string, params?: [])` which you can call. E.g `executeSQL("INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?)", ["username"]);` which handles sanitizing for you.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze yh when I insert I have:    `VALUES  1$, 2$, 3$, ... , [entrydate, activitydate, userid ...]`    something like this

Comment: Yes seems about right !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the front-end with `encodeURIComponent`:

```js
fetch(`http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:6969/api/hours/unlock/'${encodeURIComponent(value)}'`)
```

Comment: Seems to be working if I remove ' ' from ${value} but I will keep this as a backup ty.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can add the relevant `headers` to your `fetch` statement like below,

```
fetch(`http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:6969/api/hours/unlock/'${value}'`, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems to be working if I remove ' ' from ${value} but I think i will still append this to be sure ty

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just noticed that It actually works if I remove the `' '` from `'${value}'` - is it still better to check for spaces and replace them because that seems to happen automaticaly somehow.